# Returning data from a superclass in java

Tags: java, inheritance, superclass, abstraction

I have read about superclasses, abstraction etc. I understand most of the general ideas.
I have 3 classes right now (main, superclass, subclass)

First class: Grabs user miles and gallons for type of car, sends data to subclass. Subclass sets the data to variables.

I am trying to figure out a way to print the miles per gallon for the car. This calculation method lies within the superclass, but I can't find a way to print the method.
Here is my code:

Main

---

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class StartingPoint {

    public static void main (String[]args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); //Get user input

        Mercedes mCar = new Mercedes(); //Accesses subclass of the Car superclass (Mercedes)
        Toyota tCar = new Toyota(); //Accesses subclass of the Car superclass (Toyota)

        System.out.println("Do you own a mercedes or a toyota?"); //Get car type

        String carName = input.nextLine();

        if (carName.charAt(0) == 'm' || carName.charAt(0) == 'M')
        {
            System.out.println("How many miles have you travelled?");
            double miles = input.nextDouble();

            System.out.println("How many gallons have you used?");
            double gallons = input.nextDouble();

            mCar.setGallons(gallons);
            mCar.setMiles(miles);

        }

        else if (carName.charAt(0) == 't' || carName.charAt(0) == 'T')
        {
             //NOT CODED YET
        }

        else 
        {
            System.out.println("Not a valid car name for the system...");
        }





    }

}
```

Super Class

---

```
public abstract class Car {

    public double calcMPG(double miles, double gallons)
    {
        return (miles/gallons);
    }
}
```

Subclass of Superclass (Car)

---

```
public class Mercedes extends Car {

    private double miles;
    private double gallons;

    public Mercedes()
    {
        miles = 0;
        gallons = 0;
    }

    public void setMiles(double inputMiles)
    {
        miles = inputMiles;
    }

    public void setGallons(double inputGallons)
    {
        gallons = inputGallons;
    }







}
```

Comment: I added this line to my main class, not sure if it's the best way to go about doing this. System.out.println(Mercedes.calcMPG(miles,gallons));

Comment: I also figured I could add a method (calc) to the mercedes class and have it call super.calcMPG(miles,gallons) and have that method print.. System.out.println(super.calcMPG(miles,gallons) and then call mCar.calc(); and it would print.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so this is how I resolved this..

In my Mercedes class I created a method called calc. Inside the method I called:
System.out.print(super.calcMPG(miles,gallons));

Back in my main method I called mCar.calc();

This way it successfully calculated all the data and printed it.

Comment: I don't think that use of inheritance is a good idea. The sole purpose of the `Car` superclass is to make the method `calcMPG` available. The superclass should have more of a _standalone_ use to be justified. But I see that you're just beginning to use Java, so good luck with your experiments!

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification. I am new to this understanding, but I am more experimenting with how everything interacts with each other. I am hoping to improve my understanding of the idea today.

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by overriding `toString` method in superclass and then simply printing the the object with `System.out.print`. In order to make this work you have to reconstruct your superclass and subclass a little. This is the way I did it and it works, but I'm not sure if that's what you want. Hope it helps in any way.

Main method:

```
package CarProject;

import java.util.Scanner;
public class StartingPoint {

    public static void main (String[]args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); //Get user input

        Mercedes mCar = new Mercedes(); //Accesses subclass of the Car superclass (Mercedes)
        Toyota tCar = new Toyota(); //Accesses subclass of the Car superclass (Toyota)

        System.out.println("Do you own a mercedes or a toyota?"); //Get car type

        String carName = input.nextLine();

        if (carName.charAt(0) == 'm' || carName.charAt(0) == 'M')
        {
            System.out.println("How many miles have you travelled?");
            double miles = input.nextDouble();

            System.out.println("How many gallons have you used?");
            double gallons = input.nextDouble();

            mCar.setGallons(gallons);
            mCar.setMiles(miles);

        }

        else if (carName.charAt(0) == 't' || carName.charAt(0) == 'T')
        {
             System.out.println("How many miles have you travelled?");
            double miles = input.nextDouble();

            System.out.println("How many gallons have you used?");
            double gallons = input.nextDouble();

            mCar.setGallons(gallons);
            mCar.setMiles(miles);
        }

        else 
        {
            System.out.println("Not a valid car name for the system...");
        }

        if (carName.charAt(0) == 't' || carName.charAt(0) == 'T') {

            System.out.println("Miles per gallon for your Toyota is " +tCar);

        } else if (carName.charAt(0) == 'm' || carName.charAt(0) == 'M') {

            System.out.println("Miles per gallon for your Mercedes is " + mCar);

        }
    }
}
```

Superclass

```
package CarProject;

public class Car {

    double miles;
    double gallons;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.valueOf(miles/gallons);
    }

}
```

Subclass Mercedes

```
package CarProject;

public class Mercedes extends Car {

    public Mercedes()
    {
        miles = 0;
        gallons = 0;
    }

    public void setMiles(double inputMiles)
    {
        miles = inputMiles;
    }

    public void setGallons(double inputGallons)
    {
        gallons = inputGallons;
    }
}
```

Subclass Toyota

```
package CarProject;

public class Toyota extends Car {

    public Toyota()
    {
        miles = 0;
        gallons = 0;
    }

    public void setMiles(double inputMiles)
    {
        miles = inputMiles;
    }

    public void setGallons(double inputGallons)
    {
        gallons = inputGallons;
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't work because the superclass `Car` doesn't know the fields `miles` nor `gallons`. Those are only passed to it's sole `method`.

Comment: I have changed superclass `Car` a bit and now it has `miles` and `gallons` implemented. Every type of car inherits those fields and they can be set for each car differently. It should work this way, I'm new at Java also, just trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

```
 import java.io.*;

 class parent {
     int a; //VARIABLE DECLARATIONS IS ALLOWED ONLY HERE

     public void get1() throws Exception {
         DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(System.in);
         System.out.print("\n ENTER THE INTEGER:");
         a = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
     }
 }

 class child extends parent {
     int b; //VARIABLE DECLARATIONS IS ALLOWED ONLY HERE

     public void get2() throws Exception {
         DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(System.in);
         System.out.print("\n ENTER THE INTEGER:");
         b = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
    }
 }

 public class sample {
     public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
         child obj = new child();
         obj.get1();
         obj.get2();
         System.out.println("\n SUM="+(obj.a+obj.b));
     }
 }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, thank you for giving an answer to OP's question. If you add a bit more explanation to your answer this would make it even more useful for the OP and for other readers in the future. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer about how to write a good answer.

Comment: add more explanation of your answer